# Не пойму определение strongly happens before, или это ошибка в стандарте С++20 (проекте C++23)?

Tags: c++, c++20

> 6.9.2.1 Data races
> …
> 11 An evaluation A simply happens before an evaluation B if either
> (11.1)  — A is sequenced before B, or
> (11.2)  — A synchronizes with B, or
> (11.3)  — A simply happens before X and X simply happens before B.
> [Note: In the absence of consume operations, the happens before and simply happens before relations are identical. —end note]

> 12    An evaluation A strongly happens before an evaluation D if, either
> (12.1)  — A is sequenced before D, or
> (12.2)  — A synchronizes with D, and both A and D are sequentially consistent atomic operations (31.4), or
> (12.3)  — there are evaluations B and C such that A is sequenced before B, B ***simply*** happens before C, and C is sequenced before D, or
> (12.4)  — there is an evaluation B such that A strongly happens before B, and B strongly happens before D.
> [Note: Informally, if A strongly happens before B, then A appears to be evaluated before B in all contexts. Strongly happens before excludes consume operations. —end note]

Вряд ли же, к примеру варианта 12.3, в случае потока 1:
`t1 = A; atm.store(t1, model_order_release) /*B, B “синхронизируеся-с” C, т.е. B “происходит-просто-до” C */;`
И потока 2:
`t2 = atm.load(model_order_acquire) /*C*/; D = t2;`

Вычисление A будет видно ранее вычисления D во всех контекстах, т.к. вариант 12.3 целиком это же тоже "происходит-просто-до". Или я что-то упускаю и/или не понимаю?

А если это ошибка, то какое определение “происходит-строго-до” могло бы иметься ввиду? Так:

12  An evaluation A strongly happens before an evaluation **B** if, either
**(12.1) — удалён**
(12.2)  — A synchronizes with **B**, and both A and **B** are sequentially consistent atomic operations (31.4), or
**(12.x)    — A strongly happens before X, and X simply happens before B, or

(12.x)  — A simply happens before X, and X strongly happens before B, or**
(12.x)  — A strongly happens before **X**, and **X** strongly happens before **B**.
[Note: Informally, if A strongly happens before B, then A appears to be evaluated before B in all contexts. Strongly happens before excludes consume operations. —end note]

Или так:

12  An evaluation A strongly happens before an evaluation **B** if, either
(12.1)  — A is sequenced before **B**, or
(12.2)  — A synchronizes with **B**, and both A and **B** are sequentially consistent atomic operations (31.4), or
**(12.x)    — A strongly happens before X, and X simply happens before B, or

(12.x)  — A simply happens before X, and X strongly happens before B, or**
(12.x)  — A strongly happens before **X**, and **X** strongly happens before **B**.
[Note: Informally, if A strongly happens before B (**A and B in different threads**), then A appears to be evaluated before B in all contexts. Strongly happens before excludes consume operations. —end note]

Но наверное всё-таки вот так:

12  An evaluation A strongly happens before an evaluation **B** if, either
(12.1)      **— for some sequentially consistent acquire and release fence F (31.11)

(12.1.1)**          — A is sequenced before **F, and F sequenced before B**, or
(12.2)      — A synchronizes with **B**, and both A and **B** are sequentially consistent atomic operations (31.4), or
(12.3)      **— for some evaluation X

(12.3.1)        — A simply happens before X, and X strongly happens before B, or

(12.3.2)        — A strongly happens before X, and X simply happens before B, or

(12.3.3)**          — A strongly happens before **X**, and **X** strongly happens before **B**.
**[Note: For single threaded applications, an implementation may use atomic_signal_fence instead of atomic_thread_fence if there is signal processing, and eliminate it if there is no signal processing. —end note]**
[Note: Informally, if A strongly happens before B, then A appears to be evaluated before B in all contexts. Strongly happens before excludes consume operations. —end note]

P.S.
Отношение “происходит-строго-до” (этот вариант определения отношения введён в C++20, а то что в C++17 было отношением “происходит-строго-до” в C++20 стало называться отношением “происходит-просто-до”; да, в C++14/C++11 вообще было только "происходит-до"), как указано в примечании, и по смыслу его использования в остальном тексте стандарта C++20/C++23, описывает последовательное согласование видимых побочных эффектов для любых потоков и контекстов (memory_order_seq_cst). Но вариант 12.3, по фактическому тексту, является всего лишь "происходит-просто-до" длины 3 или более, которое описывает согласование видимых побочных эффектов для двух потоков и не даёт, в общем случае, никаких гарантий для остальных потоков

P.P.S.
Вроде как, ошибка во внутренней противоречивости самого текущего определения “происходит-строго-до”, утв. 12.3 противоречит утв. 12.2 и примечанию. Но, возможно, интересно использование отношения “происходит-строго-до” в тексте C++20/23:

- Отделение статической инициализации (6.9.3.2 [basic.start.static]) от динамической инициализации (6.9.3.3 [basic.start.dynamic]), и их обеих от main() основной программы и/или от любой другой не inline функции модулей трансляции;
- Отделение деструкторов локальной-памяти-потоков от статических деструкторов, от конструкторов, а так же от зарегистрированных std::atexit() обработчиков и этих обработчиков друг от друга (6.9.3.4 [basic.start.term]);
- Формальное описание связи единого общего порядка последовательно согласованных атомарных переменных и отношения “происходит-строго-до” (31.4 [atomics.order]);
- Операции освобождения (выпуска) семафоров (32.7.3 [thread.sema.cnt]), защёлок (32.8.2.3 [thread.latch.class]) и барьеров (32.8.3.3 [thread.barrier.class]), на мой взгляд, неоправданно объявлены как “происходящие-строго-до” операций захвата (получения). В принципе, атомарные переменные тоже, по умолчанию memory_order_seq_cst, но у атомарных переменных это можно изменить, а здесь такой возможности нет.  Тем не менее, смысл может быть в том, что по POSIX все вызовы всех функций синхронизации должны быть последовательно согласованы. Конечно, ради эффективности, современные реализации этого не придерживаются, но, вроде как, только в части мьютексов.

Comment: Вряд ли в такой важной вещи опечатка. Можете объяснить подобнее, что не так с этим определением?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Отношение “происходит-строго-до”, как указано в примечании, и по смыслу его использования в остальном тексте стандарта C++20/C++23, описывает строго последовательное согласование видимых побочных эффектов (memory_order_seq_cst). Но вариант 12.3, по фактическому тексту, является всего лишь "происходит-просто-до" длины 3 или более, которое описывает согласование видимых побочных эффектов для двух потоков и не даёт, в общем случае, никаких гарантий для остальных потоков.

Comment: я думаю имеет смысл задать этот вопрос на английском SO

Comment: @Serge3leo, а можно пример, где «*по смыслу его использования в остальном тексте стандарта C++20/C++23, описывает строго последовательное согласование видимых побочных эффектов*»?

Comment: @Slava, спасибо, наверное на английском и, возможно уж, что б два раза не вставать, сразу в **std-discussion**. Но, пока, вопрос и на русском изложен недостаточно внятно.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, добавил "Вроде как, ошибка во внутренней противоречивости самого текущего определения “происходит-строго-до”, утв. 12.3 противоречит утв. 12.2 и примечанию. Но, возможно, интересно использование отношения “происходит-строго-до” в тексте C++20/23:..."

Comment: @Serge3leo, да, я имел в виду, есть ли что-то в логике того, как оно используется в остальном тексте стандарта, что требовало бы именно *memory_order_seq_cst*-симантики... из того что я пробежался глазами я не могу уверенно сказать, что именно там подразумевалось — думал ты там  что-то конкретное нашёл уже... и прямо противоречия **12.2** и **12.3** я не вижу, но с примечанием последнее, действительно, расходится... и мне тоже чернтовски хочется сделать там `s/simply/strongly/`... так что версия об опечатке пока ИМХО выглядит самой правдоподобной...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну 31.4 [atomics.order], вроде как, дословно требует именно memory_order_seq_cst-семантику. Ну, и конструкторы/деструкторы и прочие std::atexit() загружаемых модулей в многопоточных программах, в общем случае, тоже должны иметь memory_order_seq_cst-семантику (как минимум, по модульно) иначе полный вынос мозга у любого, кто работает с STL будет гарантирован.

Comment: @Serge3leo, в **31.4/4**  «*if A and B are memory_order::seq_cst operations and A strongly happens
before B*» — это как раз разводит понятие `seq_cst` и *strongly happens before*, так что я бы сказал, что этот пассаж подразумевает, что ни из одно из них автоматически не следует другого... в гарантиях на счёт конструкторов/деструкторов я тоже не уверен — ... так что у меня есть ещё мутные предположения, что это всё может быть какие-то построения на счёт того, как переопределить `memory_order::consume`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, это разное, нет требования что бы всё было seq_cst, ради эффективности в единый общий порядок входят только атомарные переменные над которыми выполняются операции memory_order_seq_cst, а “происходит-строго-до” не образует единого общего порядка, грубо говоря, он относится к причинам и следствиям этих операций (т.е. которые “происходят-просто-до” них или “происходят-просто-после” них). Но под memory_order_seq_cst-семантику мы же, обычно, тоже понимаем не только сами атомарные операции, но и видимость побочных эффектов.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а с memory_order_consume в проекте  C++23 пока ничего не изменилось. Как должны были компиляторы сами разбираться в пользовательском коде: "Смогут ли ARM или POWER сами отследить зависимости, или барьер захвата (получения, чтения) надо ставить?". Так пока оно и осталось. Это другой пункт.